# Make a Background Transparent in Paint.net

Tags: transparency, paint.net

I am trying to Get Rid of Background and Make a background Transparent in Paint.net.

I have only just downloaded the software and don't know a lot about it.

Comment: Ctrl+A, Del or use one of the selection tools and mark what you want to remove.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well if you are using windows 10 V1803 and above...You can simply use Paint 3D
Its super easy to use...just click on canvas and set the background transparent toggle to active then if it a white background you can simply use the eraser and it will be transparent.
P.S - Remember to save as PNG.

Comment: more P.S - Sorry i don't know about paint.net